# How to set below layout in Android? 

Tags: android, layout

[image: layout image]

I want to do like this, which layout should i use? so that it should be compatible for all screen?
thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use LinearLayout Like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:background="@color/blue"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">            
<LinearLayout
     android:orientation="vertical"
     android:layout_width="220px"
     android:background="@color/gray"
     android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>       
    <LinearLayout     
         android:orientation="vertical"
         android:layout_marginLeft="40px"
         android:background="@color/blue"
         android:layout_width="220px"
         android:layout_height="fill_parent">
         <LinearLayout
             android:orientation="vertical"
             android:background="@color/gray"
             android:layout_width="fill_parent"
             android:layout_height="380px"/>    
         <LinearLayout
             android:orientation="vertical"
             android:layout_marginTop="20px"
             android:background="@color/blue"
             android:layout_width="fill_parent"
             android:layout_height="380px"/> 
    </LinearLayout>
```

i hope you understand, if not let me know.

Comment: i m nt getting, i have to take 4 linearlayouts or 3?

Comment: Just 2, the rest are child views. Can be anything.

Comment: see my edit, and adjust  android:layout_width,       android:layout_height these parameters depending on requirement.

Comment: that big one is an image view, and that two are textviews.

Comment: In the last 2linear layouts which view i ll give both the textview?

Comment: if i want to add 1 or 2 more textview bellow of that then which layout i should use?

Answer (score 0):

I'd use a [RelativeLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.html) if I were you. Here's an [example](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-relativelayout.html).

Answer (score 0):

Make use of layout weight and for spacing just give layout margin

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_width="fill_parent">
    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/LinearLayout01"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"></LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/LinearLayout02"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1" android:orientation="vertical">
        <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/LinearLayout03"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"></LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/LinearLayout04"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"></LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: if i want to add 1 or 2 more TextView bellow of that then which layout i should use?